# Can I change WebSocket from ws to wss? (000webhost)

Tags: php, ssl, websocket, https, unity-webgl

I had built a website as a dashboard (using 000webhost) to change the data in mySQL database via php which was working fine right now. After that, I have a Unity WebGL build uploaded on itch.io which was working fine as well until it need to get data from the database via php. When I was intended to get the data via accessing php files store in the 000webhost server, I got the following error show up in the web console from the accessing website.

Mixed Content: The page at 'https://.itch.io/' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://:54998/'. This request has been blocked; this endpoint must be available over WSS

The link I was using to access the php files was using https instead of http. I am still new to these area, I would like to know can I change the WebSocket endpoint to wss instead of ws? Do I need a paid plan to solve this? I did saw that the Single Hosting plan did offer free SSL certificate. Please help me, I am open for any suggestion/advice, Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Websocket Server itself need to setup the SSL Certificate. If it doesnt, you need a reverse proxy like nginx or apache to handle the SSL and forwarding to the unencrypted ws:// websocket.

Anyway, the websocket should run on default port 443/80 as well, since many firewalls are blocking non default ports for security reasons. In this case you will need the reverseproxy if you dont have a dedicated IP for the websocket server.

Answer (score -1):

Use [socket.io](https://socket.io/). Most of the problems are solved and there is no need to do more.

```
var socket = io.connect('https://www...', {secure: true});
```

Comment: this solves in no way the problem, since the problem is serversided.